# Want to use dates as headers in a table but need two instances of the same date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm putting together a sheet to track product sales over time. The periods of interest are weeks, so ideally I'd like to use the date of the last day of the week for column headers so that I can group into months, quarters, etc in resulting Pivot Tables. The only issue is, I really need to track both quantities sold as well as dollars made from a particular product for each week. Naming convention dictates that I shouldn't duplicate header names, so I'm not sure how to go about distinguishing the two dates (while still retaining easy grouping functionality).

I'd like something like this:

Product Name | 1/1/14 (UNITS) | 1/8/14 (UNITS) | ... | 1/1/14 (DOLLARS) | 1/8/14 (DOLLARS | ...

If pricing stayed consistent it wouldn't be a problem as I could just get the weekly dollars in the Pivot Table through a custom field, but since they can vary, this wouldn't work out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using different columns for different weeks will definitely NOT help with creating a pivot table and/or grouping data by month or quarter. Quite the opposite, actually. Spreading data for the same property over several columns makes it impossible to combine that property into a pivot table. Also, some weeks start in one quarter and end in another. If you enter data by week, how would that work with reporting by quarter or month?

What works much better is a simple table with the columns date, product name, units, dollars.

Now, you can create a pivot table and group by week (set a start date and show in groups of 7 days).

Another pivot table can then group by year, quarter, month (you need to create it with a new pivot cache, though, since groupings are held in the pivot cache).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I try to keep the table to one record per product since there are attributes (implemented as additional columns) that apply to a single product regardless of sales. For instance, keeping track of incoming units and units on hand for a given product. The positives of keeping unique records per sale are well heard -- does this mean I should be utilizing another table to capture the product-level attributes (ie. one product per row and an on-hand figure would just deduct from the sales table)?

Comment: Yes, keep product information in a product catalogue table and enter the sales data into a table with one row per transaction. You can use lookup formulas to pull data into the sales table if required.